# Deploy C#.Net Console Application

Tags: c#-4.0, assemblies, console-application, publishing

I am trying to deploy my C#.Net console application.

Methods i tried.

Build the application

1. go to **bin** directory
2. in **debug** directory copy the files and move to compressed folder
3. extract it in different machine and run **.exe** file

Problem i am having is:

I have used **MSXML2** assembly in my project.
I guess this assembly is not copied to bin directory and the machine I am running **.exe** file doesn't not having this assembly in it.

when i run the **.exe** it get below error.

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot locate the resource specified.
at MSXML2.IXMLHTTPRequest.send(object varbody
at projectname.Program.Main(String[] args))
```

how can i make sure this assembly is properly loaded to my deployed folder.

thanks for looking in to my question.

applying **dotnetengineer** suggession
set **Copy Local to TRUE**
New issue:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.MSXML2, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

Comment: Why would you deploy a debug version and not a release version?

Comment: doesn't matter. same with release version.

Answer (score 0):

Click on and highlight the reference to MSXML2 in the Soultion Explorer.  In the Properties pane, make sure "Copy Local" is set to "True".

Comment: Interop.MSXML2 this property is disabled. I cannot change it true. Only thing i can change for this is "EmbedInterop Types" and "Isolated"

Comment: See this StackExchange question and answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635716/visual-studio-copy-dll-refrences-to-output-folder

Comment: moving further but gives new exception. please look updated question with new exception

Comment: make sure you have the right "bitness" of your project compared to what the MSXML is compiled with.  If MSXML is compiled as 32-bit (most likely) change your project output to 32-bit.