# Why is the Copy Local property for my reference disabled?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I am trying to set a referenced DLL to be explicitly copied to my local folder however when I go to the properties for this reference, the `Copy Local` property is grayed out / disabled.

[image: Disabled Copy Local property]

Usually my VB.NET projects have a `My Project` item directly below the project name which I can double-click >> references and set the `Copy Local` property, however my C# console application does not seem to have this.

[image: My Project References]

Have I perhaps configured my project incorrectly? Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Change ´Embed Interop Types´ to false.

Comment: That option was also grayed out in my case. Switching to "Categorized" view enabled both of them, see comment from j.hull below!

Answer (score 102, accepted):

[Directly from this SO post:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635716/visual-studio-copy-dll-refrences-to-output-folder)

> Your comment to Hans answer indicates this is a COM assembly and that
>   you are using Visual Studio 2010.
>
> This means the assembly reference was likely added with the "Embed
>   Interop Types" setting set to true. This has the effect of linking the
>   COM assembly into your binary removing the need to deploy it
>   altogether. The following link has a more detailed explanation 
>   •http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409610.aspx   If you do
>   want to deploy it though then will need to do the following  •Click on
>   the reference in the references tab  •Hit F4 to bring up the
>   properties grid  •Set "Embed Interop Types" to False (this will ungray
>   Copy Local)  •Set "Copy Local" to true

If you want to copy local, you must set `Embed Interop Types` to `False` for the assembly, in your case, `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`. Embed Interop Types makes deployment easier for COM assemblies in that it embeds the assemblies within your assembly, taking away the need to deploy interop assemblies with the application.

Comment: Interesting side note, you need to have the properties box set to categorized and not alphabetical.  For some reason by alphabet locks the change capability

Comment: Though this is an old question, wanted to add that an attempt to do this caused my build to fail, (in my case, citing that a number of methods such as .Delete() on the Sheets class couldn't be resolved)