# Dependent DLL is not getting copied to the build output folder in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, dll, reference

I have a visual studio solution.
I have many projects in the solution.
There is one main project which acts as the start up and uses other projects.
There is one project say "ProjectX". Its reference is added to main project.
The ProjectX references another .NET dll (say abc.dll) that isn't part of the solution.

Now this abc.dll should be copied to bin/debug folder of main project, but it isn't getting copied there. Why is it not getting copied, any known reasons ?

Comment: if you can't figure this out then copy it in your prebuild.

Comment: how do you use your 'ProjectX' in the main project - what's the type of the project, target etc.

Comment: I had the same issue and this answer solved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8213977/174469

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Msbuild doesn't copy references (dlls) if using project dependencies in solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132243/msbuild-doesnt-copy-references-dlls-if-using-project-dependencies-in-solution)

Comment: there is `RestoreProjectStyle` [solution available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50510696/940182). The idea is to set `<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>` for each .Net Framework project in the solution.

Answer (score 130):

I found that if ProjectX referenced the abc.dll but didn't directly use any of the types DEFINED in abc.dll, then abc.dll would NOT be copied to the main output folder. (It would be copied to the ProjectX output folder, to make it extra-confusing.)

So, if you're not explicitly using any of the types from abc.dll anywhere in ProjectX, then put a dummy declaration somewhere in one of the files in ProjectX.

```
AbcDll.AnyClass dummy006; // this will be enough to cause the DLL to be copied
```

You don't need to do this for every class -- just once will be enough to make the DLL copy and everything work as expected.

**Addendum:** Note that this may work for debug mode, but NOT for release. See @nvirth's answer for details.

Comment: This seems like a hack.  Adding the reference to the main project seems to be enough.

Comment: It IS a hack, but as today's CodeProject news taught us, even compilers can be wrong!

Comment: Adding a reference in the main project did not work for me.  Only adding the dummy reference got the compiler to copy the referenced dll.

Comment: Adding a reference to the main project wasn't enough. I had to create a dummy field in one of the classes to get the assembly copied over to the output directory.
This approach is acceptable for test code, as is the case here, but I'd rather see a more robust solution for solving this issue for production code.

Comment: How crazy things can be. @OverlordZurg your solution worked as I had a reference to the dependent dll in my XAML (WPF) and it didn't copy the DLL to the main project until I add a simple dummy reference as you told ... Thanks anyway

Comment: This is the way I always use. I don't want to put a reference to every dependent project. It seems wrong to me..

Comment: @MohsenAfshin I had the same issue---I was referencing a dependent DLL in XAML. Instead of declaring a dummy variable, however, I simply named the component I was using in XAML, and that was enough to cause its assembly to be copied.

Comment: @MikeK Adding it to the main project (which doesn't actually directly depend on it) is an even bigger hack, imo. Then you have to manage it two places ("manage" as in upgrade or remove). With *this* hack, at least you get a nice compile time error reminding you to remove this hack when you remove the dependency, and you still only need to update it in one place.

Comment: Was happening to me for a data layer library which only used extension methods.  (Dapper)  When the consumer of the library was built, it didn't detect the dependency correctly and didn't copy the dapper assembly, resulting in an ugly FileNotFound exception.

Comment: Calling `GC.KeepAlive(typeof(SomeTypeInProblematicAssembly));` at some point is sufficient for the dependency to be traced.

Comment: WpfAnimatedGif only adds attached properties to XAML elements, so wasn't being copied and there are no constructable objects in the library.  This line in the window constructor works for me, though, both in Debug and Release: `string copyMePlease = WpfAnimatedGif.ImageBehavior.AutoStartProperty.Name;`

Answer (score 98):

Just a sidenote to Overlord Zurg's answer.

I've added the dummy reference this way, and it worked in Debug mode:

```
public class DummyClass
{
    private static void Dummy()
    {
        var dummy = typeof(AbcDll.AnyClass);
    }
}
```

But in Release mode, the dependent dll still did not get copied. 
This worked however:

```
public class DummyClass
{
    private static void Dummy()
    {
        Action<Type> noop = _ => {};
        var dummy = typeof(AbcDll.AnyClass);
        noop(dummy);
    }
}
```

This infomation actually costed me hours to figure out, so I thought I share it.

Comment: in release mode, optimizer assume that "dummy" is not used so this line is unnecessary and should be removed.
but when you use "dummy" in code, optimizer doesn't assume itis unnecessary.

Comment: this doesn't work for me.AbcDll.AnyClass still isn't copied to other project

Comment: Make sure `AbcDll.AnyClass` is used as a public field or property on a public class, then it will work. If you use it in a method body like this the compiler doesn't _see it_. It will delay load this assembly, not what you want to happen.

Answer (score 64):

Yes, you'll need to set `Copy Local` to `true`. However, **I'm pretty sure** you'll also need to reference that assembly from the main project and set `Copy Local` to `true` as well - it doesn't just get copied from a dependent assembly.

You can get to the `Copy Local` property by clicking on the assembly under `References` and pressing F4.

Comment: @Brij, is the assembly referenced from the **main project** you want it in? As I stated, **I'm pretty sure** you need to reference from that project as well - dependent assemblies aren't copied over like that. If that were the case you wouldn't need to add the assemblies to all relevant projects when using NuGet.

Comment: I created a sample solution in Visual Studio. In that, the dependent dll is getting copied in the main project.

Comment: @Brij, what's the difference between the two solutions then? Are you referencing the outside assembly exactly the same way as in the other solution?

Comment: yes, the dll is at desktop and the project is referring that dll. And the project is referenced in main project.

Comment: @Brij, then that must mean the referenced project, from the main project, is setup differently in the working solution. Press `F4` on the references project under the main project's References and see what the differences are between the two.

Comment: No difference other than the name and path.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27573/discussion-between-michael-perrenoud-and-brij)

Comment: what was the conclusion here? It seems to me that you are right - dependent references are not copied even if CopyLocal is set to true - what is the logic behind that?

Comment: @mcmillab, in short Visual Studio doesn't **infer** dependencies from other dependent projects. If project A references project B, project A will need to have all of project B's references. It works nicely when all project B needs is .NET assemblies, but if it's a 3rd party assembly you must add the reference to both projects.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I don't think that's true. If you look at a detailed MSBuild output you will see calls to [ResolveAssemblyReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad3f294.aspx) which states it "includes second and nth-order dependencies". This also concurs with what I see in my bin folders (n-th dependencies get copied). The issue is there are some caveats about what is copied, mostly around GAC and indirect references (Add Reference is sometimes not enough)

Comment: I've seen this myself- My model project references a 3rd party dll (A), which requires another 3rd party dll (B)- I reference model from my web project and publish, and B.dll doesn't appear causing a silent problem breaking part of the system.  Very annoying.

Comment: I have seen the same thing. What is the conclusion?

Comment: My current experience is that this will work *except* for 'copied' dependencies: project A.net references external C++ dlls as files which are 'copy always'. Project B.net references Project A. On build, B/Debug includes the C++ dlls. However, when I build Application X, which references Project B, the C++ dlls *sometimes* get copied (seems to be only if I do a Rebuild).

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is *wrong*. It doesn't need to *infer dependencies*, it just needs to *copy output* (from one project's bin to another's), which MSBuild does, at least normally.

Comment: @MikePerrenoud I dont think thats true either (that you need to reference all references that Project B has). I have this issue now, where ProjectB is references from my MainProject and I get the error. I was hoping that VS understood that reference chain went like _"ProjectA-->ProjectB-->ProjectC-->multiple DLLs including the 'cannot resolve'-DLL"_. But it fails. But, in another project, I have "ProjectOther-->ProjectB-->ProjectC-->..." but ProjectOther ALSO references ProjectC directly, and then manages to run as expected.

Comment: @Ted I think this behavior is actually proven via NuGet. When you reference a NuGet package in ProjectA, then reference ProjectA assembly in ProjectB, you'll have to add that NuGet package to ProjectB for the build to work.

Comment: Nops, I dont think so. Im not sure what u mean with "proven via NuGet" or "NuGet package", but I have many many DLL-references in _Project C_ that are not referenced in _Project B_ or _Project A_ in my chain, that looks like this: _Project A ==> Project B ==> Project C_. And it builds, but sometimes fails in runtime as described above.

Comment: To put it simply: your project must reference dependencies of its dependencies. Which I find completely nonsensible.

Answer (score 40):

It looks slick when you make it an assembly attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly)]
public class ForceAssemblyReference: Attribute
{        
    public ForceAssemblyReference(Type forcedType)
    {
        //not sure if these two lines are required since 
        //the type is passed to constructor as parameter, 
        //thus effectively being used
        Action<Type> noop = _ => { };
        noop(forcedType);
    }
}
```

The usage will be:

```
[assembly: ForceAssemblyReference(typeof(AbcDll.AnyClass))]
```

Comment: Thank you, but for me this only does something when I add the assembly attribute to the dependency (Project X), which already references the AbcDll.AnyClass. And then, it doesn't do more than normally, where it copies the AbcDll to the dependency's output directory. It still does not copy it to the main dependent project's output. And I cannot add the attribute to the dependent assembly unless I also add a reference to AbcDll. When I do that, AbcDll already gets copied without the attribute.

Answer (score 30):

Ran into this same issue.  Background info: before building, I had added a new Project X to the solution.  Project Y depended on Project X and Project A, B, C depended on Project Y.

Build errors were that Project A, B, C, Y, and X dlls could not be found.

**Root cause was that newly created Project X targeted .NET 4.5 while the rest of the solution projects targeted .NET 4.5.1.**  Project X didn't build causing the rest of the Projects to not build either.

**Make sure any newly added Projects target the same .NET version as the rest of the solution.**

Comment: Referenced projects may be an older version of .NET. I'm able to reference a project built for .NET 4 by a project built for .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 23):

Not sure if this helps but for me, many times I reference a DLL (which automatically adds it to the bin folder of course). However that DLL might need additional DLLs (depending on what functions I'm using). I do NOT want to reference those in my Project because they just simply need to end up in the same folder as the DLL I am actually using.

I accomplish this in Visual Studio by "Adding an existing file". You should be able to add it anywhere except the Add_data folder. personally I just add it to the root.

Then change the properties of that file to ...

Build Action = None  (having this set to something like Content actually copies the "root" version to the root, plus a copy in the Bin).

Copy to output folder = Copy if Newer  (Basically puts it in the BIN folder only if it is missing, but doesn't do it after that)

When I publish.. my added DLL's only exists in the BIN folder and nowhere else in the Publish location (which is what I want).

Answer (score 11):

You could also check to make sure the DLLs you're looking for aren't included in the GAC. I believe Visual Studio is being smart about not copying those files if it already exists in the GAC on the build machine.

I recently ran in this situation where I'd been testing an SSIS package that needed assemblies to exist in the GAC. I'd since forgotten that and was wondering why those DLLs weren't coming out during a build.

To check what's in the GAC (from a Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt):

```
gacutil -l
```

Or output to a file to make it easier to read:

```
gacutil -l > output.txt
notepad.exe output.txt
```

To remove an assembly:

```
gacutil -u MyProjectAssemblyName
```

*I should also note, that once I removed the files from the GAC they were correctly output in the \bin directory after a build (Even for assemblies that were not directly referenced in the root project). This was on Visual Studio 2013 Update 5.*

Comment: Thanks, you are right, MSBuild will not copy dll to output folder if it found them in the GAC.

Answer (score 8):

If you right Click the referenced assembly, you will see a property called **Copy Local**. If Copy Local is set to true, then the assembly should be included in the bin. **However**, there seams to be a problem with Visual studio, that sometimes it does not include the referenced dll in the bin folder... this is the workaround that worked for me:

[image]

Comment: Copy Loal was disabled, this helped https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526491/why-is-the-copy-local-property-for-my-reference-disabled

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that the dependent DLL used by you does not have target .NET Framework higher than the target .NET framework of your project's Application.

You can check this by selecting your project, then press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>, then select Application from left side and then select Target Framework of your project.

Suppose,
dependent DLL Target Framework = 4.0 and
Application DLL Target Framework = 3.5 then change this to 4.0

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Issue:

Encountered with a similar issue for a NuGet package DLL (Newtonsoft.json.dll) where the build output doesn't include the referenced DLL. But the compilation goes thru fine.

Fix:

Go through your projects in a text editor and look for references with "Private" tags in them. Like True or False. “Private” is a synonym for “Copy Local.” Somewhere in the actions, MSBuild is taking to locate dependencies, it’s finding your dependency somewhere else and deciding not to copy it.

So, go through each .csproj/.vbproj file and remove the tags manually. Rebuild, and everything works in both Visual Studio and MSBuild. Once you’ve got that working, you can go back in and update the to where you think they need to be.

Reference:

https://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2008/02/13/what-to-do-if-copy-local-works-in-vs-but.aspx/

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was the stupidest thing, caused by a default behavior of TFS/VS that I disagree with.

Since adding the dll as a reference to the main project did not work, I decided to add it as an "Existing Item", with Copy Local = Always. Even then the file was not there.

Turns out that, even though the file is present on the VS Solution and everything compiled both locally and on the server, VS/TFS did not add actually add the file to source control. It was not included on the "Pending Changes" at all. I had to manually go to the Source Control Explorer and explicitly click on the "Add items to folder" icon.

Stupid because I've been developing for 15 years in VS. I've run into this before, I just did not remember and somehow I missed it because everything still compiled because of the file being a regular reference, but the file that was added as Existing Item was not being copied because it did not exist on the source control server.

I hope this saves someone some time, since I lost 2 days of my life to this.

Comment: I can't thank you enough... you saved me so much time.  This was solution for me.  It also exposed the root problem, the DLL I added as a reference matched a `gitignore` pattern, so when adding as a reference it did not add to the project.  You MUST manually add the file to source control!!!

Answer (score 2):

This is a slight tweak on nvirth's example

```
internal class DummyClass
{
    private static void Dummy()
    {
        Noop(typeof(AbcDll.AnyClass));
    }
    private static void Noop(Type _) { }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do add it to Postbuild events to copy necessary libraries to the output directories. Something like XCopy pathtolibraries targetdirectory

You can find them on project properties -> Build Events.

Comment: This worked for me, and I think this is the better answer.  The dummy reference solution works, but it's a hack, whereas a post-build rule is a clean way to accomplish the same result.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR; Visual Studio 2019 may simply need a restart.**

I encountered this situation using projects based on Microsoft.NET.Sdk project.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

Specifically:

- `Project1`: targets `.netstandard2.1`

  - references `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console` via Nuget
- `Project2`: targets `.netstandard2.1`

  - references `Project1` via a Project reference
- `Project2Tests`: targets `.netcoreapp3.1`

  - references `Project2` via a Project reference

At test execution, I received the error messaging indicating that `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console` could not be found, and it was indeed **not** in the output directory.

I decided to work around the issue by adding `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console` to `Project2`, only to discover that Visual Studio's Nuget Manager did not list `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console` as installed in `Project1`, despite it's presence in the `Project1.csproj` file.

A simple shut down and restart of Visual Studio resolved the problem without the need to add an extra reference. Perhaps this will save someone 45 minutes of lost productivity :-)

Comment: Actually I restarted the whole PC on my way of testing things but it worked for me

Comment: I'm having the same problem with SDK project .NET5 , I tried this solution but unfortunately it didn't work for me, even after restart the PC :(

Answer (score 1):

You may set both the main project and ProjectX's build output path to the same folder, then you can get all the dlls you need in that folder.

Answer (score 1):

**NO NEED FOR DUMMY IN CODE**
Just :

> add a Reference to the Executeable Project

or/and ensure that the reference in the executeable project has `"Copy Local"` set to `TRUE` (which was my "*fault*") is seems that this *"overwrote"* the setting in the base referenced library-project...

Answer (score 0):

Other than the common ones above, I had a multi-project solution to publish. Apparently some files target different frameworks.

So my solution: Properties > Specific Version (False)

Answer (score 0):

Add the DLL as an existing item to one of the projects and it should be sorted

Answer (score 0):

VS2019 V16.6.3

For me the problem was somehow the main .proj file ended up with an entry like this for the project whose DLL wasn't getting copied to the parent project bin folder:

```
<ProjectReference Include="Project B.csproj">
  <Project>{blah blah}</Project>
  <Name>Project B</Name>
  <Private>True</Private>
</ProjectReference>
```

I manually deleted the line `<Private>True</Private>` and the DLL was then copied to the main project bin folder on every build of the main project.

If you go to the reference of the problem project in the references folder of the main project, click it and view properties there is a "Copy Local" setting. The private tag equates to this setting, but for me for some reason changing copy local had no effect on the private tag in the .proj file.

Annoyingly I didn't change the copy local value for the reference, no idea how it got set that way and another day wasted tracking down a stupid problem with VS.

Thanks to all the other answers that helped zone me in on the cause.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in which a DLL I had included in the project as content and 'Copy always' set, wasn't being copied to the bin folder. I solved this by adding a dependentAssembly reference to the DLL in the app.config.