# VS solution's props and target setting not copying files to output directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, cefsharp

I am using `CEFSharp` in a WPF project. Along with regular .Net dlls, `CEFSharp` need some exe and unmanaged dlls to be present in output directory.

To send those dlls, CEFSharp adds, props and target details in solution file & they end up in output directory.

In my WPF Solution, all Third Party Packages (TPP) are installed in a separate project **which is referred by Shell project**.

So the solution hierarchy is like this

```
Solution
   |- Shell
   |- Third Party Projects
```

But strangely, they end up in TPP's output directory but do not end up in shell's output directory.

Why is that?

Comment: That is known problem - VS will not copy indirect references unless you use them in main project. There are some complications to that as I remember - it's not that simple, but in general you should not rely on copying indirect references. See this question for example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15816769/5311735

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/pull/1753