# Copying dll to executable path

Tags: c#, dll, sdk

I am planning to use a third party sdk in my program, and documentation says copy the .dll file to your c# 32 bit executable path. I am not sure what to do here. Could you guys please help?

Comment: This means, copy the dll file to the folder where your other dll for this project are

Comment: If you are using visual studio I think you can add the dll to the refences of the project, and that will do the job

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dependent DLL is not getting copied to the build output folder in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816769/dependent-dll-is-not-getting-copied-to-the-build-output-folder-in-visual-studio). Have a look at these answers, they are gonna solve your problem