# How to load referenced assemblies, especially those referenced via Nuget

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-assembly, nuget-package

A dll that is referenced via Nuget but not used yet is not available if I query AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies or EntryAssembly.GetReferencedAssembly. How can I load the dll. I want to register some types from it and won't use any compile time solution, but run-time.

Comment: have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816769/dependent-dll-is-not-getting-copied-to-the-build-output-folder-in-visual-studio) maybe you've got the same problem

Comment: very little in common. have already gone through. Putting dummy declaration solves the problem but in my case even that is not applicable

Comment: What stops you from adding a dummy reference?

Comment: it just look very unprofessional to add a line that means nothing but to force .net to load the assembly that contains that type. I'm sure there could be a better solution. Moreover the developers using my framework code won't always remember that they they have to add a dummy type.