# Use MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit in a WPF UserControl library

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design-in-xaml

I would like to create a wpf UserControl library utilizing the MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit.

Obviously a library does not have the `App.xaml` file that the quick start guide suggests. I was under the impression, that I could use the `Themes\Generic.xaml` file plus the `ThemeInfo` attribute in `AssemblyInfo.cs` but that does not work (apparently this works only for CustomControls) - it cannot resolve the resources.

Is there a way to make this work in a wpf class library?

```xml
<Grid>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedAccentButton}"
            Foreground="{StaticResource SecondaryHueLightBrush}"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either install the NuGet package and reference the resource dictionaries in the `App.xaml` file of the consuming application, or install the package and reference the same resource dictionaries in the control itself in the library:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfControlLibrary1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfControlLibrary1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedAccentButton}"
            Content="Test"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Make sure that the MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf and MaterialDesignColors assemblies are copied to the output directory of the app when you build:

[Dependent DLL is not getting copied to the build output folder in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816769/dependent-dll-is-not-getting-copied-to-the-build-output-folder-in-visual-studio)