# Transitive dependent DLL is not found during runtime

Tags: c#, dll, nuget-package

I have a csproj A, in which I added a dependency for D.dll. I have taken a dependency on A in project B with normal project reference not the dll type reference.

When I run the unit tests of B then it is failing in Runtime saying that D.dll is not found.

The build is successfully passing for all the projects.

One interesting thing to note about there is a DLL which is referenced by there projects which would call a method in D.dll using refection. This particular reflection method is failing by saying that the D.dll method is not found.

I do not want to include D.dll in the csproj of B, is there any way I can follow? [If I add the dependency in D.dll the runtime tests pass]

I have tried adding `<private>True</private>` as far as I have understood this will help to copy the dll in the output directory and help the build of A.csproj not the b.csproj. Adding the dummy class in A.csproj did not work.This solution did not work for me - [Dependent DLL is not getting copied to the build output folder in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816769/dependent-dll-is-not-getting-copied-to-the-build-output-folder-in-visual-studio)

This can be thought of How can a transitive dependent library be copied to the output folder without adding explicit reference