# How to Set the Copy Local Property to true in visual studio community 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to set Copy Local property to True in visual studio 2015 but When I change it from false to true and move to the next property, the value changed back to false

Comment: can someone please help me

Comment: I have a small web application. Which was working fine in server but am trying to run the code in local system its showing some error

Comment: Hope this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526491/why-is-the-copy-local-property-for-my-reference-disabled

Comment: This link will you help i guess https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/t1zz5y8c(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 13):

[image]

You will need to do the following

- Click on the reference in the references tab
- Hit F4 to bring up the properties grid
- Set "Embed Interop Types" to False (this will ungray Copy Local)
- Set "Copy Local" to true

Comment: Where is "Embed Interop Types"? Maybe a screenshot will help

Answer (score 0):

This could caused by "global Settings"

Check if there is a **Directory.Build.props**-File somewhere in the folder that contains your source, and remove it.

For background see my Answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50755604/1196586